# What happens in KOTOR 2 if I kill one Jedi Master and spare 2?

Tags: star-wars-kotor-2

I'm curious what happens when I encounter Jedi Masters on Dantooine near the end if I kill one and spare two?

I've done full LS (spare all) and DS (kill all) approach, but haven't tried the hybrid.

UPDATE: I know that Jedi Masters will be gone, whether by Kreia (LS) or me (DS), but I'm more specifically curious if they are aware that one of them was killed by PC.

Comment: if I remember correctly, its been a long time (so I'll just comment).  Even if you kill one of them previously, they'll treat you with hostile intent and fight you at that scene.

Answer (score 7):

Finally had a chance to do this with a DS character with Restoration Mod: Jedi Masters sense that Exile has killed one of them, and then attack. Dialog Kreia will do afterwards is same as DS when all Jedi Masters are dead.

Comment: Can't remember the mechanics of the choices in question, but can you not spare the first two and then kill the third? Or does this not make sense in context?